# Sub query returns more than 1 row

Tags: php, mysql

My web site is a cafeteria. The user logs in and orders. When the same user logs in twice, the sub query error appears. What are the possible ways to solve the sub query problem?

Comment: post your sql query

Comment: What is the code and what is the error, can you explain more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your subquery returns more than a single row, you can use an `IN` clause to  manage more rows:

```
select * from my_table
where id in (select id from table2 where ....)
```

Or you can obtain a single result using an aggregation function:

```
select * from my_table
where id = (select max(id) from table2 where ....)
```

Comment: Done ... Thank you

Comment: @peterh   ..many thanks for the grammar correction  ..English is not my language  ..